# MongoDb: How to transform existing document to expected structure?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The existing `MongoDB` document looks like this:

```
  {
    "_id": "unique_id",
    "name": "some-name",
    "description": "some-description",
    "modified": "11-11-2021",
    "modifiedBy": "root"
  }
```

I need to change the structure of the document, as a result of transformation I expect to see the following Document:

```
  {
    "_id": "unique_id",
    "name": "some-name",
    "description": "some-description",
    "changes": [
      {
        "modified": "admin",
        "modifiedBy": "root"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I've tried the following aggregation query:

```
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      description: 1,
      changes: [
        {
          "$modified",
          "$modifiedBy"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

But code above concatenates fields in the array as Strings, but I want to see 1 element in the array that is embedded document, not separate strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields), as the name implite it adds the new fields, and then use the `$project` to [exclude](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html#exclude-fields) the `modified` and `modifiedBy` fields.

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "changes": [
        {
          modified: "$modified",
          modifiedBy: "$modifiedBy"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      modified: 0,
      modifiedBy: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Output:

```
 [
  {
    "_id": "unique_id",
    "changes": [
      {
        "modified": "11-11-2021",
        "modifiedBy": "root"
      }
    ],
    "description": "some-description",
    "name": "some-name"
  }
]
```

Comment: your example doesn't do exactly what I need.

Comment: Let's make it work. Do you want to actually update the document? or the result from a find operation?

Comment: no, I just asked about transformation to Array, but your code does the transformation to Object

Comment: I just updated my code acordaly, but I think @grodzy's answer is nicer.

Answer (score 1):

You projected to some array. You can project into objects as well

```
db.dummy.remove({})
db.dummy.insert({name:'n', description:'d', modified:'now', modifiedBy:'me'})
projo = {
  name: 1,
  description: 1,
  changes: [
    {
      modified: '$modified',
      modifiedBy: '$modifiedBy'
    }
  ]
}
printjson(db.dummy.findOne({}, projo)) // mongo >= 4.4 or use aggregate
/*
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("6041c873b051129dbb0c0f72"),
  "name" : "n",
  "description" : "d",
  "changes" : [
    {
      "modified" : "now",
      "modifiedBy" : "me"
    }
  ]
}
*/
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DgiHg3JMEit)